# Why does this website not scale to fit on the iphone on load?

Tags: iphone, html, mobile

The client is complaining that the site doesn't fit in an iphone screen, how come other websites rescale to fit the screen but the site below doesn't?

http://berrisford.gumpshen.com/

Answer (score 3):

Because it has a viewport meta tag which doesn't allow so:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

Comment: Even without the viewpoint meta tag it still doesn't scale, that is why I added it. Could you maybe provide a solution please?